# Detect bad driving actions from speed in C#

Tags: c#, gps, obd-ii

I have speed tracked from an OBD port or GPS. It is measured in miles per second. There is an event that gets triggered each time new speed is updated, how can I detect, fast acceleration in this speed over time? For example, the car is going at 30mph, and suddenly accelerates quickly to 100 in only a few seconds?

Also, similar would apply to harsh braking too, where speed is dropped too fast.

Comment: 'detect' is one thing but not a full spec. You will have a sequence of measurements, some below and some above a limit. What information do you want to distil from this?  Real time ?

Comment: I'm making an app for my dissertation that tracks how user drives and gives feedback. I want to be able to detect whether a car is harshly accelerating or braking. Once such an event is detected, I want to send it off to a server and then I can do something useful with it, eg calculate total driving score based on the events and display it to the user along with some feedback. I do want the data to be processed in real time, as the car is driving.

Answer (score 2):

Acceleration is the first derivative of speed. You have to calculate the speed increase/decrease over time, maybe over immediate samples.

Reflecting the comment I go into details:
You have a callback in each second with the actual speed. You have to calculate the  speed difference between calls, that is the acceleration in miles/second^2. Save this acceleration result (preferably packed with the current speed and a timestamp) in a list. After this keep the current speed for the next second.

```
private double LastSpeedSample;
private void OnNewSample(object sender, SampleEventArgs e) {

    double Acceleration = LastSpeedSample - e.Speed;
    // Pack and save calculated value
    LastSpeedSample = e.Speed;
}
```

Comment: I know that I have to calculate this, the trouble I am having is with the actual code part of it. I am not sure where to start. Based on the fact that the speed is received from an event, how can I constantly be calculating this over time in real time? I need to have initial and final velocity, then divide change in velocity over time. But because the speed changes even every second or so, where would I store the initial and last velocity? Would it be between each events?

Answer (score 0):

acceleration can be measured in miles/second/second or miles /s^2.
you can just take the difference between 2 measurements and calculate the acceleration from these measurements. for example, if you go from 2 to 5 miles per second in 2 seconds. that means you have an acceleration of 1.5 miles / s^2. Or if you go from 5 to 2 miles per second the nit is -1.5 miles/s^2

so there are 2 things you need:

2 measurements and the time between them.

so if you take a measurement every second then you just take the difference between the measurements and take this as your acceleration/deacceleration value.